# PHPUnit outputs only question marks

Tags: php, linux, phpunit

when I try to run phpunit the only output is a question mark `?`

```
benino@benino-VirtualBox:/$ phpunit
?benino@benino-VirtualBox:/$ 

benino@benino-VirtualBox:/$ phpunit --version
?benino@benino-VirtualBox:/$
```

I get the same output if I actually try to run a test.

I then downloaded the current version of `phpunit` as follows:

```
$ wget https://phar.phpunit.de/phpunit.phar
$ php phpunit.phar --version
```

The output of that last command is:

```
??r????
```

I have no idea what's wrong. 
running `php 5.3.8` on Ubuntu

Comment: Have you tried it with the code version from composer or github? Maybe there's something wrong with the phar. I never saw a problem like that.

Comment: I am not positive but you may want to try adding `detect_unicode = Off` to your php.ini file. Had a very similar issue although it was with composer and not phpunit.

Comment: Had the same problem and this was the only post on the Internet about it. @mschuett suggestion actually fixed it for me also.

Comment: Support for PHP 5.3 ended on August 14, 2014. For security reasons consider an upgrade to PHP 5.6 or 5.5. It *will* solve your problems.

Answer (score 4):

Just adding this as an answer since it looks like at least my solution helped one other person.

If you are running into this issue it is highly likely due to the version of php having dectect_unicode turned on. You can simply modify your php.ini file to have `detect_unicode = Off` and the output should be shown properly.

http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.zend.detect-unicode for more info.